# Should ActiveRecord DirtyColumns be cleared when calling Save

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am checking whether my class IsDirty, if so the user gets prompted to with a "do you want to Save" message.  If they click yes, it calls a Save however I am stuck in a loop because Save does not clear out the dirty columns.

Should it?

****BUMP****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its a bug and logged on github.com